# BIND PTR doesn't show in MXtoolbox

Tags: bind

I have problem with my PTR records that doesn't work when I set my DNS to google DNS for example or when I check them with the MXtoolbox,

I had to cover the customer IP address [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaxG4.png)

and when I use my DNS it works [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZpQe.png)

Comment: Please do not use images to convey important details for your question, inline the parts as text, and also please remember that any obfuscation you do may hinder getting proper and relevant answers. The DNS is public, there is no sense trying to hide information.

Answer (score 0):

PTR records are checked in reverse. So for example when checking 8.8.4.4, the dns-lookup would be 4.4.8.8.in-addr.arpa. 
Read more about it here to learn about PTR records: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

Comment: If you use `dig -x` option it does everything needed by default and you do not have to worry (because for IPv6 addresses you would have a lot of work to reverse the thing, and the suffix to use is different anyway)